# Каким образом определяется необходимость вызова деструктора для объектов с автоматической продолжительностью хранения?

Tags: c++, компиляция, c++11

Рассмотрим простой пример:

```
void f();
void f_exception();

class A {
  private:
    std::string m_name;

  public:
    A(std::string name) : m_name(name) {/*NOP*/}

    ~A() {
        std::cout << "Destroy object \"" << m_name << "\"." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    f();

    try {
        f_exception();
    } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cout << "Catch exception." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void f() {
    A a("a");

    std::cout << "Before block" << std::endl;
    {
        A b("b");
    }
    std::cout << "After block." << std::endl;
}

void f_exception() {
    A c("c");

    std::cout << "Before block" << std::endl;
    {
        A d("d");
        throw std::runtime_error("exception");
    }
}
```

Стандарт гарантирует, что объекты с automatic storage duration будут удалены при выходе из блока кода, в котором они объявлены. Я предположил, что при компиляции создаются соответствующие инструкции, но ведь выход из блока может быть осуществлен и ранее (при использовании исключений, оператора `goto`, оператора `return` и т.д.). Т.е. необходимость вызова деструктора должна определяться динамически при выполнении программы. Это и подтверждает приведенный выше пример (вывод в консоль):

> Before block
>   Destroy object "b".
>   After block.
>   Destroy object "a".
>   Before block
>   Destroy object "d".
>   Destroy object "c".
>   Catch exception.

Собственно интересует, как это реализуется во время выполнения программы.

Comment: А вы в ассемблерный вид скомпилите и посмотрите, return в скольких местах он не написан обычно превращается в jmp в конец функции, где происходит размотка стека там же и деструкторы вызываются

Comment: С ассемблером совершенно не знаком, но спасибо за совет - попробую посмотреть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему динамически? Все инструкции известны компилятору, а это значит что он для всякой инструкции, которая ведёт к «покиданию» текущей области может добавить вызов деструктора(ов). Здесь нет никакой магии, и не требуется анализа рантайма — просто работа для компилятора.

Кстати, вот это:

> Стандарт гарантирует, что объекты с automatic storage duration будут удалены при выходе из блока кода, в котором они объявлены.

Не совсем правда. Попробуйте написать `exit(0)` в коде — Вы не увидите ни одного деструктора или попробуйте добавить `noexcept` к функции `f_exception()` — будет похожий результат.

Comment: То есть в каждом возможном месте выхода из блока добавляется инструкция по вызову соответствующих деструкторов?
По дополнению: проверил и правда деструкторы вызваны не были. Спасибо, не знал.

Comment: @PavelParshin Ну скорее от опций отпимизации зависит, если оптимизировать по скорости, то может добавить и туда же где выход. А если по размеру - то наверняка все способы выхода в объектном коде соберет в одном месте и сделает туда jmp (jmp в asm это goto)  Но скорее всего при любой оптимизации он пойдет именно по второму пути, это для вас выход из функции return, а для компилятора обычно это приличный объем работы, по размотке стека, восстановлению регистров иногда по проверке стека и дублировать он его не будет

Comment: @PavelParshin, я честно не знаю, никогда не анализировал эту ситуацию, то, что я описал это просто один из способов реализации. Я уверен, что можно сделать и умнее и компиляторы делают очень умные вещи. Описанные Вами случаи, в вопросе, полностью видны компиляторам и они с лёгкостью их обрабатывают. Остаются случаи с исключениями, которые выбрасываются в функциях и пробрасываются вверх по стеку — для этого у компиляторов тоже есть хитрые трюки, но они чего-то стоят. Т.е. это можно считать динамическим анализом — все функции(без noexcept) автоматически считаются опасными.